# Why can't I do a kinit with an SPN?

Tags: kerberos, spnego, apacheds, gssapi, keytab

I was following this [tutorial](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/kerberos-ug/4.2-authenticate-studio.html) on setting up Apache Directory Studio for a webapp to develop and test out kerberos authentication (using spnego). I set up the ldap and ticket granting service as well as some basic user accounts. I am able to do a kinit with the user accounts, so I know that portion is working well.

So, the current logs from that are indicating that it cannot decrypt the ticket. I tried using the keytab file with kinit and it wasn't working, so then I just tried to do a kinit and manually type in the password - which also doesn't work (even after verifying the password is correct in Apache Directory Studio). Here is the ldif file I used for creating the spn:

```
dn: uid=HTTP/example.com,ou=users,dc=security,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: krb5KDCEntry
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: krb5Principal
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
cn: HTTP/example.com
krb5KeyVersionNumber: 1
krb5PrincipalName: HTTP/example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
sn: Something
uid: HTTP/example.com
userPassword: secret
```

whenever I do a `kinit -V HTTP/example.com` and type in the password, I just get:

```
HTTP/example.com@EXAMPLE.COM's Password: 
kinit: Password incorrect
```

This is my krb5.conf:

```
[libdefaults]
debug = true
default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM

[realms]
EXAMPLE.COM = {
    kdc = example.com:60088
    admin_server = example.com:60088
    default_domain = EXAMPLE.COM
}

[domain_realm]
.example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, apparently you cannot setup an SPN that is the same as the default realm. I had to create a subdomain (myapp.example.com) and import the associated new ldif file:

```
dn: uid=HTTP/myapp.example.com,ou=users,dc=security,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: krb5KDCEntry
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: krb5Principal
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
cn: HTTP/myapp.example.com
krb5KeyVersionNumber: 1
krb5PrincipalName: HTTP/myapp.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
sn: myapp
uid: HTTP/myapp.example.com
userPassword: secret
```

After that, I was able to kinit with `HTTP/myapp.example.com`. I was then able to setup a keytab and load that into my webserver and got SSO working!